# Nested find or aggregate in mongo

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Below is structure of the documents in my json file. I want to display the first name and surname of each winner grouped by the year they won.

Comment: What is your expected output? Plz add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
db.winners.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$prizes"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        name: {
          $concat: [
            "$firstname",
            " ",
            "$surname"
          ]
        }
      },
      years: {
        $push: "$prizes.year"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      name: "$_id.name"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

You can [see the result here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LhsdzPyQsc2)

We basically first need to flatten the `prizes` after which just group by the concatenated `firstname` & `surname` and then push the `years`.

Rest is just so we can get the name to appear instead of the `_id` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all winners of a same year you can do this:

```
db.winners.find({year:1},(err, winners)=>{
let winnersList = [];
winners.forEach(winner =>{
     winnersList.push(winner.firstname, winner.surname);
//Or watever you wish to do with it.
     }
}
```

Easy way is getting all the objects from year you want then use what you need of  it, just my personal opinion. Hope it helps.